# Wordpress audio link not working

Tags: audio

I'm trying to add an audio file to a page. I've added the audio file to my media library, and added it to the page using the "Add Media" button. It added the following text:

```
[audio mp3="http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/6.mp3"][/audio]
```

The problem is that on the page itself, this generates a link, that leads to that same page, without passing along the file.

I've changed the domain name in the above snippet because the domain name the site is currently on is temporary while my domain registrar is updating dns settings.

Comment: When you view this shortcode in the Text mode (instead of the Visual mode) is it still the same?

Comment: Yes, it looks the same.

Comment: Does it work in the default theme without any plugins?